# Bing Maps with XAML and C# in Metro Style App

Tags: c#, xaml, bing-maps, windows-8, microsoft-metro

It's possible to use Bing Maps with XAML and C# in Metro Style App on Windows 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

A beta release of Bing Maps for Metro Style Apps came out in March, this should be what you are looking for.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846481.aspx

Simple usage example: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/06/bing-maps-for-winrt-xaml.aspx

Comment: At the moment, the control is quite primitive.  I have written an open source project that extends Bing Maps for metro to provide annotations, callouts and more.  You can find it here: https://github.com/carlospuk/metromapmanager

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the WebView Control to host any HTML content. The simplest example would be

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF0C0C0C">
        <WebView x:Name="bingMapsView" Width="1050" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

and set the URL in your code.

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri("http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx");
bingMapsView.Navigate(targetUri);
```

You can use http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/ to figure out how to use the bing maps SDK.